# In Search of: Universal Video Format

Tags: video, embed, h.264, quicktime

I'm playing whack-a-mole trying to make an embedded video file work on all major browsers.

It's just a Quicktime h.264 .mov and .m4v file but if I use  it doesn't work in IE, and if I use the Quicktime JS Prototype code it doesn't work in Firefox. Of course .flv won't work with IOS.

Is there a format/method of embedding that works on all major current browsers "out of the box"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woud use H.264 codec in MPEG-4 (MP4) container.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Davyd, any recommendations on how best to embed into a page?

Comment: I suppose you mean a web page. The best method I know is to use HTML5 native video tag. The movie file should be segmented first in order to be used with it. I use Apple media file segmenter.